# Zend_Json encode double quotes showing as & quot;

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

I am running a simple Zend_Json::encode($data) command, then adding it to an array, then sending it off to process by a 3rd party site.

I have it logging the request data being sent to the other site, and everything looks good except the data that I encoded. It seems to be using & quot; instead of the actual double quotes.

So as an example, my $data is a simple associate array that contains the following data

```
$data['user_id'] = 5
$data['email'] = 'john@email.com'
```

I created an array of the encoded data as well as an extra ID the 3rd party needs, so I did it like so.

```
$sendParams = array(
    'userData' => Zend_Json::encode($data),
    'tokenId' => '4403-3493-22'
);
```

Then I converted  it to XML and sent it to them.  In my log, the request I sent looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Request action="EvaluateUser">
    <ParameterList>
        <userData>
            {&quot;user_id&quot;:&quot;5&quote;,&quote;email&quote;:&quote;john@gmail.com&quote;}
        </userData>
    </ParameterList>
    </Request>
```

As you can see it's not using actual quotation marks.

I can't seem to figure out how to convert it to regular double quotes.  I've tried str_replace but that didn't seem to affect the xml request at all.

Thanks!

Comment: you'd need to show how you're building that xml. zend_json::encode would return a regular JSON string with quotes as expected. If you're doing `htmlspecialchars()` or other transforms on that json string, then that's where `&quot;` is coming from. You're probably better off putting the raw json string into the xml inside a cdata block.

Comment: Thanks Marc! You're right there was an htmlspecialchars in another function the parameters were sent to.